# Attaching a file to an email message

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have an HTML form that, when submitted, calls a PHP script on my server. The elements of the form (recipient's address, subject line, body) get sent to the script and an email is generated and sent. This all works great.

I would like to expand on this and allow the user to select a file from their local machine and send that off to the server to get sent as an email attachment. Can this be done with my current architecture? Also would this be in the JavaScript code on the client side since the file is coming from their local machine or in the PHP script?  I didn't think JavaScript could do something like this but I've seen similar tools that open a file browsing window so it must be possible but maybe it isn't JavaScript. Any good advice on where to start or how to do this would be great.

Answer (score 2):

> Can this be done with my current architecture?

Yes, it is possible to attach files to emails using PHP.

> Also would this be in the javascript code on the client side since the file is coming from > their local machine or in the php script?

The form on the client side will prompt the user to select a file to upload (using an `<input type="file" />` form element and setting the `enctype` of the form to `enctype="multipart/form-data"`), which will be uploaded to the server. From there, the server is responsible for converting the attachment into a format that is acceptable for the email (i.e. base64_encoding the file). Once the file is base64_encoded, it must be properly formed into the email so it is understood as an attachment at the recipient.

Googling "sending email attachment in php" yields many tutorials, including these:

- http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/send_email_text_html_attachment.php#attachment
- http://www.texelate.co.uk/blog/send-email-attachment-with-php/

Answer (score 1):

Use a multipart form in HTML like this:

```
<form action="send_email_with_attachment.php" method="post"enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Select file to attach:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And then concatenate the file contents to the message string to send using [PHP's mail function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). Make the email header (in the message string) have a content-type that is [multipart](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html) with a boundary and separate the email body from the file contents with the boundary string (you can choose any random string you want). If the file were an image, it might look something like this (where the long character string is a base64 encoding of the image file):

```
To: Someone
Subject: Test HTML email
From: SomeoneElse
Reply-To: Nobody
MIME-version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p
Date: Tue,  29 Nov 2011 09:55:36 +0100 (CET)


--gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hello World!!!
This is simple text email message.

--gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p
Content-Type: image/png; name="img.png"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: xxxx
Content-Disposition: inline, filename="img.png"

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==

--gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p--
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly - this is done with PHP, not Javascript. When run in a browser, Javascript has no access to the local file system.

The first thing you will need to do is add an `<input type="file">` to your form, make sure the `method` of the form is `post`, and add/change the `enctype` attribute of your `<form>` element so that it is `multipart/form-data`. Information about a successful file upload will then be available in PHP in the `$_FILES` array - [see here for more information](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) on handling file uploads in PHP.

Next, you need to change the way that you generate your email. If you use something like [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/) or [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) (and using one of those is recommended), you will just need to read the respective documentation for how to add attachments you your messages. If you use `mail()`, and want to continue to use it, you will have to learn how [multipart MIME messages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages) work.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need JavaScript for this (in fact all you could use it for in this example would be to add some bling). This would be the HTML part:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="__URL__" method="POST">
Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
```

This would be the PHP part:

```
$uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    // handle success (add $uploadfile as attachment to the mail)
} else {
    // handle error
}
```

Code taken from php.net (http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php).

Comment: This is for a generic file upload, and requires saving the uploaded file to non-temporary disc space (which is not required). How does this apply to email attachments, or more specifically, the OP?

Comment: @nickb: OP is asking for **pointers** and I think this was a good one. StackOverflow **is not** a free coding service. Zrvan's answer, I believe, is a valuable one.

Comment: @Icarus - A direct c/p from the docs without explaining the application to the OP's subject is not an answer. Not sure why you mentioned "a free coding service", I never said we should code the OP's request (as you could tell by my answer), nor do I need **bold text** to understand what you're saying.

Comment: @nickb I agree that I could have been a bit more inquisitive as to the exact email solution that the OP uses, but this is "good advice on where to start". As to the storage part not being required, this is a reasonable assumption by you, but not necessarily true.

Comment: @nickb: Zyrvan explained that Javascript is not required for this (something the OP seemed to believe) and then provided an example on how to achieve it with pure HTML. I think that clarifying the Javascript misconception and providing the sample code answered the question (Is it possible with my current architecture? -> Yes, provided code. Need Javascript? -> No) so I think it's a valuable answer and hence the downvotes are unfair (Note: I am *not* saying that you downvoted his answer). Could have this been answered better? Sure. Is it an incorrect answer or does not address the question? No